# How to deal with CORS error on iOS devices with ionic framework

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cors, ionic4, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using ionic 4 to view a woo-commerce website with woocomerce API, my app works well with android but when I try to run my app on iOS device I get this error

```
Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I'm using wordpress and woocommerce plugin and ionic native 4

Comment: You should handle CORS in backend

Comment: Is there any tutorial or documentations that may help?